# Discord.py rewrite failed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am keep getting this error Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-RQYKe_/aiohttp/ what is the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: When does this happen and how can it be reproduced?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I don't know probably thats why I asked on stackeroverflow?

Comment: You need to tell us when the error happens so we can tell you why it happens and how to fix it.

Comment: Ah okay. The error happens when I used "pip install -U discord.py"

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install discord.py` on its own without the `-U`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work after I ran the command in terminal then, I ran on_ready it in my code editor and saying Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rtrt/discord.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "/home/rtrt/discord.py", line 2, in <module>
    from discord.ext import commands
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.ext'; 'discord' is not a package

Comment: Check my answer and try one of those commands in CMD, if you get notified that it successfully was installed then restart Python and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception because your `setuptools` or `pip` may be out of date, run these commands to upgrade them then try to install `discord.py` again:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip

pip install discord.py
```

Then restart Python and import the modules like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

Comment: It says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rtrt/discord.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "/home/rtrt/discord.py", line 2, in <module>
    from discord.ext import commands
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.ext'; 'discord' is not a package
when I did that.. Am I doing something wrong? My code was import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('yeeee')
    
client.run('token')

Comment: Did you have any issues when you ran `pip3 install discord.py`? Or did it say "Successfully installed discord.py"?

Comment: It said ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. so, basically yes I did and no it didnt say that

Comment: Try to run `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip` and then try to install discord.py again.

Comment: It is saying it is already satisfied and when I try to run a basic command with the same modules you provided and a @client.event async def on_ready print('yeee') then client.run('token') it's saying there is no module or package

Comment: You need to close your bot file fully then re-run it and it should work.